# post request JSON returns null

Tags: android

When I put mu url in postman and I put my 3 parameters in the body I find response content a code or in android my variable content the response return "null"

I did not understand why.

my class:

```
public  class task extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, Void> {
private Context applicationContext;
public HttpEntity responseBody;
public  static String respons;
MainActivity activity;
public  task(MainActivity activity){
  this.activity=activity;
}


@Override
public Void doInBackground(URL... voids) {
    respons=new String("");

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

   HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://recrutement.stb.com.tn:1010/PlateformeApi_Externe/api/");
 
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList< NameValuePair >(5);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "sami"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "stb"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AuthMethod", 
    "FormsAuthentication"));
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        Log.d("myapp", "works till here. 2");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.d("myapp", "response " + EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
           respons = String.valueOf((response.getEntity()));
          // respons=response.
          // responseBody=(response.getEntity());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    return null;
   }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    String s=respons;
  }

   @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
    //Show something on ui like Progress Dialog etc here
    super.onPreExecute();

  }

    public Context getApplicationContext() {
    return applicationContext;
  }

  }
```

the MainActivity : I called my class and I see my variable in toast message

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {                                       
 Button bo;
 URL url;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bo=findViewById(R.id.button);
    bo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            task logIn = new task(MainActivity.this);
            logIn.execute(); 
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"code="+logIn.respons,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      
        }
    });
  }
}
```

[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIawu.png)

Comment: Try making `respons` variable global to both classes. It's not a good idea to threat `AsyncTask` as long lived object used to store variables. Also, try using `Log.d()`  instead of Toast, you'll debug much quicker.

Comment: At the time you make the toast the response is null. you need to return your response in the onInBackground(...). And do the toast in the on post execute. Also your do onInBackground(...) shall return the response string instead of void

Comment: thanks,but i do what to say i have this problem  "                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()" in this line             "                    respons= EntityUtils.toString(entity);"

Comment: @OuertaniSaiid Can you post the whole stack trace